# This does not seem to work, No error messages. nothing happens, probably a simple fix. I am new

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I dont get any error messages. it all seems to be fine, but when i try doing something like .8ball literally nothing happens.

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

client2 = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready. ')

    @client2.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'pong {round(client2.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client2.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(cxt, *, question):
    responses = ['nah fam',
                 'maybe fam',
                 'yes fam']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')
```

Comment: Try referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049873/no-command-responses-using-discord-py-rewrite) similar question, it may be of help. [This doc reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) may also be of use.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you cannot run 2 client instances at a time.
Simply, Just follow this following code:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready. ')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'pong {round(client2.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(cxt, *, question):
    responses = ['nah fam',
                 'maybe fam',
                 'yes fam']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Your issue is FIXED.

Comment: disregard that, it went back to just simply not working. maybe its because im running anaconda in pycharm for this but its strange

Comment: welp, i uninstalled literally everything and got my bot to work again. but the command still doesnt work. not using conda anymore either

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK OMFG ITS BEEN HOURS THAT IVE WORKED ON IT, THANK YOU FAM

Comment: the code is inflicting on another piece of code I have going on. although still the 8ball command wont work "ctx.send" part of the code. specifically the ctx. the other code. for the .ping the command below is conflicting                                                                                                                                                     @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    if message.content.find('!help') != -1:
        await message.channel.send('I got you fam, just message SlaySoup ')

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
                                                                                                                                                  So yeah it doesnt work when i put that code in along with it and im not sure why